# Can the discharge of the water powered backup sump pump be connected to the discharge of the primary sump pump?

Tags: plumbing

When installing a water powered back-up sump pump can the discharge of the water-powered back-up sump pump be connected by a Y to the discharge of the primary sump pump? I read that it shouldn't according to the Uniform Plumbing Codes and IAPMO PS119. Also what is the proper distance  between the back up sump pump float and the primary?

Comment: You "can" do anything, but the entire point of a backup system is in the event the primary fails. What would happen if the primary discharge tube gets clogged or otherwise prevents discharge? Codes/guidelines are usually there for a reason, even if they can be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Put check valves on both discharge lines upstream of any "Y" connection to prevent back feeding through the unused pump.